# An ERROR 1064 occurs while creating a table using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a new table after starting MySQL service.

I code it at Win10, on MySQL 8.0 command line Client. The code now is shown as below:

```
create table 't8' ('id1' timestamp not null default current_timestamp,'id2' datetime default null);
```

Then I got an error while I was executing it:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''t8' ('id1' timestamp not null default
>   current_timestamp,'id2' datetime defaul' at line 1

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Remove the ' around the tables and column names and replace it with `

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Comment: You r right. But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this.

```
create table t8 (
    `id1` timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
    `id2` datetime default null
);
```

Comment: Because table and column names are not meant to define with single quote notation, because according to sql code syntax the way to define table and columns is this `
You can check in phpmyadmin or any other tool to generate any query like create update or delete.

Answer (score 0):

Try below - instead of single quote '' you need to use back tick `` or you can keep it just id1 or id2

```
create table t8
(
  id1 timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
  id2 datetime null
)
```

Comment: An alternative way! Thx~